# Storing a photograph as Blob using Android and PHP

Tags: php, android, image, blob

I am currently working an an Android application which is dealing with pictures, and uploading them to a database.
The app first uses the device's camera, then sends the generated Bitmap to an AsyncTask which will call a PHP API to update the database with the image as a mediumBLOB and additionnal data (int and String).

The AsyncTask encodes the Bitmap into a String, and sends all the needed data as a POST request to the PHP page.

The PHP page then gathers the data, converts the String into a BLOB image, and uses them in a mysqli request to insert a new row in the database table.

**UPDATE :** Thank you for the feedback. I changed the PHP code, to use bind variables.
Although, as I set the image as a parameter, the request makes a new table row with an empty BLOB.
I know the usual method is storing images somewhere else and using their name/url in the database ; but in my case using BLOBs is a requirement.

Here is the Android code for the AsyncTask :

```
public class DBTaskImageSending extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
    static final String TAG = "asyncSend";

    private final String PARAMETER_PLACE = "location";
    private final String PARAMETER_IMAGE = "image";
    private final String PARAMETER_COMMENT = "comment";
    private final String PARAMETER_OWNER = "owner";

    Context mCContext;
    UploadActivity mUAMain;

    //The PHP page address :
    String mURLAdress;

    //Data to send to the PHP page :
    String mComment;
    int mID_Photographer;
    int mID_Event;
    String mImage; //The image in its final conversion before sending it.

    public DBTaskImageSending(String url, UploadActivity ua, Context c, Bitmap img, String comment, int place, int owner)
    {
        this.mURLAdress = url;
        this.mCContext = c;
        this.mUAMain = ua;

        this.mComment = comment;
        this.mID_Event = place;
        this.mID_Photographer = owner;
        this.mImage = conv_Image_String(img);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.i(TAG, "Request sent to "+mURLAdress);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"__________________________________________________");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings)
    {
        try
        {
            sendImage(mURLAdress);
            Log.i(TAG, "Object sent !");
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Sending failed.");
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void sendImage(String url) throws IOException
    {
        //Loading the POST data :
        String mSCryptedData = URLEncoder.encode(PARAMETER_PLACE, "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Integer.toString(mID_Event), "UTF-8");
        //----- owner ID :
        mSCryptedData += "&" + URLEncoder.encode(PARAMETER_OWNER, "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Integer.toString(mID_Photographer), "UTF-8");
        //----- Image comments :
        mSCryptedData += "&" + URLEncoder.encode(PARAMETER_COMMENT, "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mComment, "UTF-8");
        //----- the image itself :
        mSCryptedData += "&" + URLEncoder.encode(PARAMETER_IMAGE, "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(mImage,"UTF-8");//*/

        ContentValues mCV = new ContentValues();
        mCV.put(PARAMETER_PLACE,mID_Event);
        mCV.put(PARAMETER_OWNER,mID_Photographer);
        mCV.put(PARAMETER_COMMENT,mComment);
        mCV.put(PARAMETER_IMAGE,mImage);

        try {
            //Eestablishing connection :
            final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(5000); // milliseconds
            conn.setConnectTimeout(5000); // milliseconds

            //Setting up and sending the data :
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter mOSW = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            mOSW.write(mSDataCryptee);
            mOSW.flush();

            //Gathering the server's response:
            readResponse(conn.getInputStream());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.i(TAG,e.getCause().toString());
        }
    }

    private void readResponse(InputStream pISBuilder) throws IOException
    {
        Log.i(TAG,"readR : Entering...");
        BufferedReader mBR = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pISBuilder));
        String ligne;

        Log.i(TAG,"readR : Starting to read");
        //Gathering the PHP response :
        while ((ligne = mBR.readLine()) != null)
        {
            Log.i(TAG,ligne);
        }
    }

    //* Function to convert the Bitmap to String :
    private String conv_Image_String(Bitmap imgOrigin)
    {
        if (imgOrigin != null)
        {
            //The image is first converted to byte[] (or Blob), before being encoded to String.
            ByteArrayOutputStream mBOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imgOrigin.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,10, mBOS);
            byte[] mBytImg = mBOS.toByteArray();

            String mStrImg = Base64.encodeToString(mBytImg, Base64.DEFAULT);
            return mStrImg;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }//*/

}
```

I remade the PHP code, so here is the new version:

```
<?php
if ((isset($_POST['location']) AND isset($_POST['owner'])) AND (isset($_POST['comment']) AND isset($_POST['image']))) {
    $location = $_POST['location'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $owner = $_POST['owner'];
    $image = base64_decode($_POST['image']);

    $image_b = imagecreatefromstring($image);

    //*
    if ($image_b == false) {
        echo "error_image";
    }
    else {

        $image_temp = imagegd($image_b, 'tmp');
        $image_f = fopen('tmp',"r");
        $image_blob = fread($image_f,filesize('tmp'));

        sendData ($location,$comment,$owner,$image_blob);
    }
}
else {
    echo "error_parameters";
}

function sendData($p_location,$p_comment,$p_owner,$p_image){
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "****", "****", "**DBName**", "3306");
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    else {
        mysqli_query($conn, 'SET NAMES \'utf8\'');
        $sqli = "INSERT INTO bar_a_image_test.Photo(
            ID_Localisation_Photo,
            ID_Photographe,
            Date_Photo,
            Ecartee,
            Commentaire_Photo,
            Image_Photo)
        VALUES
            ( ? , ? , NULL, 0, ?, ? )";

        if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sqli));
        {
            $stmt->bind_param("iisb",$p_location, $p_owner, $p_comment, $p_image);
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        $conn->close();
    }
}
?>
```

The new problem now is that the query loads all the data in the database, except the image. It just records an empty BLOB in the new row.
I am looking for a way to effectually convert the image (encoded to a string) to a BLOB.
As I previously mentionned, I have to use BLOBs, although external storage is more frequent.

Comment: Your query is implemented in a horrible way and is open to XSS errors.  Never use string concatenation or interpolation for SQL queries, use bind variables instead.

Comment: The usual method is to save the image in a file and save the file name in the DB.

Comment: Honest opinion is this isn't the best way to do it and I would suggest using something like Firebase. Firebase is free and will actually let you do real time updates. Plus, they handle all the security for you. If you aren't a security expert it's probably best to not try to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @ZackMatthews If you think firebase is free, you have only very small apps.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thank you for the feedback. I updated the code with bind_param. Although the image is still not loaded, the SQLi query works without error.

Comment: @GabeSechan "freemium," sure. Not that I know the scale of what OP is building, but depending on how much use it could definitely be cheaper than web hosting.

Comment: @ZackMatthews Actually, I work on a project for a private company, they already have their own server (which I use) and they intend to use it for the data storing.
I'm not sure using Firebase is relevent solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Gabe Sechan who advised me to use bind_param, I eventually found a solution.
It is all in the bind_param declaration:

```
$stmt->bind_param("iisb",$p_location, $p_owner, $p_comment, $p_image);
```

Instead of declaring the decoded image as a Blob (the "b" at the end of the first parameter), I declared it as a string (replacing the "b" by an "s").
Making the method called this way:

```
$stmt->bind_param("iiss",$p_location, $p_owner, $p_comment, $p_image);
```

And the image is perfectly loaded as a Blob in the database.
Thank you for the support!